# MYSQL many to many grouped by multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have a table with fields `id`, `person`, `question`, `answer`. So it's a vertical many-to-many(?) table...

I would like to get the counts of people who have answered given answers from 2 questions, split by the answer to those questions, for example:

(Question 1 has 5 answers (1,2,3,4,5), Question 2 has 2 answers (0,1))

```
`question_1_answer`,    `question_2_answer`,    `count`
1,  0,  3
1,  1,  2
2,  0,  2
2,  1,  5
3,  0,  3
3,  1,  4
4,  0,  2
4,  1,  3
5,  0,  2
5,  1,  2
```

I can do it if I just want to look at 1 Question (with id 2 in this example):

```
SELECT 
`answer`,
COUNT(DISTINCT `person`) AS "count"
FROM 
`table` 
WHERE 
`question` = 2 AND
`answer` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `answer`
```

Which gives something like:

```
`answer`,   `count`
1,  5
2,  7
3,  7
4,  5
5,  4
```

But I cannot figure out how to do the thing I'm asking for, nor find examples of such by searching. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the counts per person by using conditional aggregation. Then count answer pairs.

```
select answer1, answer2, count(*)
from
(
  select 
    person,
    max(case when question = 1 then answer end) as answer1,
    max(case when question = 2 then answer end) as answer2
  from answers
  group by person
) persons
group by answer1, answer2
order by answer1, answer2;
```

You can add a `WHERE` clause to the inner query in case there are more questions and you want to speed up the query.

Add a `HAVING` clause to the inner query, if it's possible for persons to answer only one of the questions, but you want only persons answering both.

Comment: Does this assume there is a table called answers? Because in my case, there isn't - the answers have to be stored as JSON for the input and output of the system - EDIT: Ignore me, I got this to work!

Answer (score 0):

You should first build two tables, one with the answers from question 1 and the other with the answers from question 2. After that, you can join them using `person` and use the `count()` function.

```
CREATE TABLE question_1 AS 
  SELECT id, person, answer as question_1_answer FROM table 
  WHERE question = 1 AND answer IS NOT NULL;

CREATE TABLE question_2 AS
  SELECT id, person, answer as question_2_answer FROM table
  WHERE question = 2 AND answer IS NOT NULL;

SELECT question_1_answer, question_2_answer, count(DISTINCT person) as count
FROM question_1 JOIN question_2 ON question_1.person = question_2.person
GROUP BY question_1_answer, question_2_answer;
```

Sorry, I didn't test my code. It may not work.